# error in running a sh file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a simple sh file but I'm failing in trying to install the software. I firstly ran the command:

`chmod +x azx_installer.sh`

then I enter this one:

`sh azx_installer.sh`
but it gives me the following error:

`chmod: cannot create /home/andrelima/Desktop/azx.desktop: Directory nonexistent`

what is happening around here?

Comment: This is because in your script you are trying to do some stuff that is incorrect. Share your code so we can see what can it be.

Comment: Does the directory `/home/andrelima/Desktop/` exist?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to make the script executable **AND** additionally run it inside sh.
Using the syntax

`sh script`

is fine. If you make the script executable you have to check the magic cookie too (to learn more, please ask google for "**Shebang**").

Then you can use the syntax:

`sh -x script`

to see the commands, that are executed. It is called **xtrace** (google(sh xtrace)).
It is a nice feature, give it a try.